# Not smoothing the rear

Tags: shaders

I am trying to create a bar, that has a rounded end. I did this by creating a cylinder with 32 vertices, extruding the outward-facing faces, and then deleting the middle and back. This seems to work fine, but when I apply shade smooth I get 2 issues.

1. The smooth facing does not seem to affect the inside of my half cylinder
2. Where my cylinder ends and becomes along bar I got some shading artifacts

The form from the top
[image: The form from the top]

Issues: Here you can see my backside is not being shaded smooth, and the transition to the long bar is not being shaded correctly as well
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making sure your entire mesh is shaded smooth (right-click context menu in object mode). Sometimes your mesh can have a mix of shaded flat/smooth faces when doing operations like object merging, even if you have Auto Smooth turned on.

Next I would check for doubled vertices or interior faces. Judging by how the wireframe is thicker where one of the hard edges is a good indicator for overlapping geo. You can get rid of overlapping verts by running the **Merge by Distance** operator (found in the M context menu).